# Difference between $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h)-f(x)$ and $dy$

Tags: calculus, limits

I was told that we can not treat Leibniz notation as ratio because infinite small $(dx,dy)$ doesn’t exist in Reals because of Archimedean property and its not used in standard calculus.

But doesn’t $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h)-f(x)$ also mean infinite small change?

Comment: No. This quantity is a constant that is zero for a continuous function. The concept of a limit requires finite values not "infinitely small" ones.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous, $$\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)-f(x)$$

is exactly $0$.

If $f$ is discontinous, the limit can be undefined or be any finite value.

When a limit exists, it is a plain number.

---

In modern concepts, $dy$ is no more an *infinitesimal*, it is a linear application defined as $y'(x)\,dx$, where $dx$ is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, while Leibniz was working on calculus, he used these "infinitesimals" such as $dx$ to explain his conlusions. Nowadays we don't really separate $dx$ and $dy$. We rather use them to intuitively understand calculus. Rigorously it only makes sense to talk about the limit of a ratio, not ratio of limits, since in the definition of a derivative the denominator always tends to zero.